# using Xstream is possible serialize methods?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xstream

I have a Java object like this:

```
class A{
  public int id;
  public double hours;
  public int getMinutes(){
    return hours * 60;
  }
}
```

I would like serialize the class A using the xstream.toXml method in this way;

```
A a = new A();
a.id = 10;
a.hours = 2.5;
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
xstream.toXML(a, writer);
```

to output this this result:

```
<A>
<id>10</id>
<minutes>150</minutes>
</A>
```

Is it possible? There is a special XStream annotation that can be used? Should I use some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is create my own Converter that implements:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter
```

Comment: Hi could you please show the solution how to implement a converter for the methods?

Comment: Of course! Please look at xstream docs here http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html . The key-point is the class `PersonConverter` that implements `Converter` and the registering of it using `xStream.registerConverter(new PersonConverter());`